# How do you name a class that exposes both methods for serialzing and deserializing / marshaling unmarshaling

Tags: java, refactoring, naming-conventions

how do you call a class that both performs serialization and deserialization. Or that performs both Marshaling and unmarshaling. Programming language is Java but I guess the question is agnostic.

Example class signature:

```
public class SampleObjectMarshler {

    public String marshal(SampleOject object);

    public SampleObject unmarshal(String)
}
```

If I call it Marshler it would be wrong because it also perfoms Unmarshling. What would be a correct name ?

Comment: I would use toObject and parseString as method names

Comment: @bubbles it is a network format.

Comment: It will be good to use specific to context or domain or any business functionality for any type of developers.

Comment: @Sambit what context do you need beyond that I would like to perform marshlig/unmarshling and cut the edge by placing it in the same class. What context would you need in addition to that ?

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov you can marshal/serialize on disk too, will you change the name ?

Comment: If this is a concrete implemetation for, as you say, some sort of format for transmitting the object over the network, why not name the class ```NetworkRepresentation``` making it clear the purpose of the serialised format. If you need to marshall for other scenarios, then you might want to extract an interface and have the concrete implementations implement it. The method names are verbs that indicate what action is being performed and the class name should be a noun that gives some context to that.

Comment: @0xadecimal naming it NetworkRepresentation  would depict only the marshaling aspect again, but not the unmarshaling in my opinion.

Comment: @0xadecimal Converter kind of captures the two way nature of the processing. Although I am not sure I like it either.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov - Yeah, because then you will have converter in the class name and (un)marshall in the method name, which is kind of confusing. I guess Transformer is just the same.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov, you can use generic type T and you can use convert from one type to another. It will be more specific to your domain context rather than saying marshall and unmarshal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Kafka calls this kind of component a [Serde](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Serde.html), short for Serializer/Deserializer.